# Не работает Animation Starter Pack, как можно решить проблему?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unrealscript

[image: На фотке, изображена ошибка]

Я просто хочу заменить анимацию, из Animation Starter Pack. Меня анимацию, но компилятор не принимает его

Comment: Здравствуйте, Вы просто скопировали эту часть из блупритна, который был в примере?

Comment: Я просто добавил это пак к проекту. И он не работает

Answer (score 0):

не могу написать в комментарии, напишу так: В Skeletal Mesh указать надо загруженные анимации. К чему скрин был приложен? Предупреждение о неизвестной зависимости. Может кнопку не указали в настройках ввода или само действие отсутствует в тех же настройках ввода? Если скопировали с примера, то нужно создать этот самый InputAction Crouch и назначить на клавишу нужную вам. Проверьте наличие Animation Blueprint - содержит в себе логику воспроизведения анимаций.